# Know the hidden row in LIMIT sql lite query

Tags: sql, sqlite, limit

I am trying to analyse a sqllite database and I use these data for a bar chart. I will count and do the avg of age group by each value in each column, in this case `Class` with the limit of only first 100 distinct values.

An example of this table:

```
Age  Class

25   Worker   
30   Student  
48   Spy
```

I use `LIMIT 100` to limit the result. To add more information for user, I want to let user know the number of values didn't get in account and the hidden rows, is there anyway to achieve this?

Simple solution: I am not very familiar with sql so I think to do two queries, with and without `LIMIT`, count the number of rows and substrat each other to find the answer. But because I have 42 columns so I would be very happy if I can have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all but the first 100 rows, you can combine `LIMIT` with `OFFSET`.

```
select * from test01 LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 100;
```

Comment: so how can I know how many rows is hidden? should I count the result?

Comment: select count(*) from test01 LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 100;